# Knuth Euclid algorithm worst case

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm, golden-ratio

I have been reading Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming(vol 2. Seminumerical Algorithms) and noticed the following statement:

> If $0 \le u,v < N$, the number of division steps needed by the Euclidean algorithm to process $u, v$ is at most $\lfloor log_\phi(3 - \phi)N \rfloor$.

Now the following [website](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LamesTheorem.shtml) which prompted me to read the book states the same except that the maximum number of steps is in fact $\lceil log_\phi(\sqrt{5}N)\rceil - 2$.

Am I missing some algebraic manipulation here if this actually represents the same or is it a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

$ \phi=\dfrac{\sqrt5+1}2
\implies\phi^2=\phi+1$ and $3-\phi=\dfrac {\sqrt5}  \phi.$

Also, since $\log_\phi(3-\phi)$ is not an integer, its floor differs from its ceiling by $1$.

Comment: Can you fully work it out from the first version to the second? I am not that good with algebra.

Comment: $ \phi=\dfrac{\sqrt5+1}2
\implies\phi\,^2=\phi+1$ and $2\phi-1=\sqrt5\implies3\phi-(\phi+1)=\sqrt5\implies$ $3\phi-\phi\,^2=\sqrt5$ $$\implies3-\phi=\sqrt5/\phi\implies \log_\phi(3-\phi)=\log_\phi( \sqrt5) -1\implies\lfloor \log_\phi (3-\phi)\rfloor=\lceil\log_\phi \sqrt5\rceil-2$$

Comment: Can you please tell me which area of math I need to improve in to be able to do what you did there myself? I might have went into this book too early.

Comment: Seems like algebra